# Pass current product_id to a Model in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to give django a try by developing a simple page where people can ask something about a product

This is my model, i can create products in the admin area, display the product page, and the form shows up with the fields email, and text.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()

class Question(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, default=?, editable=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    text = models.TextField()

class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
```

But i don't know how to tell the model which product id the question has to be saved to.

This is my views.py

```
# other stuff here
def detail(request, product_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    f = QuestionForm()
    return render_to_response('products/detail.html', {'title' : p.title, 'productt': p, 'form' : f},
    context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def question(request, product_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    f = QuestionForm(request.POST)
    new_question = f.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('products.views.detail', args=(p.id,)))
```

And the URL

```
urlpatterns = patterns('products.views',
    (r'^products/$', 'index'),
    (r'^products/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', 'detail'),
    (r'^products/(?P<product_id>\d+)/question/$', 'question')
)
```

Righ now it works if i put a "1" in the default attribute for the product foreign key in the question model (where the question mark is), it saves the question to the product  id 1. But i don't know what to do to make it save to the current product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either:

**Send `product_id` as form value**

Make [`product` foreign key in your form a hidden field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621212/another-django-forms-foreign-key-in-hidden-field) and set it's value to primary key value of the product in `detail` view. This way you **don't** need a `product_id` in your `question` view URL and arguments since the ID will be passed with `POST` data. (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621212/another-django-forms-foreign-key-in-hidden-field) for examples)

*Id would use this option, since you'd have cleaner `question` URL and you could do more validation in your form on the product.*

or

**Send `product_id` through URL**

Use [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) in your `detail` view to build the form `action` attribute or use  [`url` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url) to build the `action` attribute in form template. This way you need `product_id` in your `question` URL and arguments but you don't need `product` field in your `QuestionForm`. Then in `question` view simply get the product instance and set it as FK value on `Question`.

---

**Example:**

Using `url` template tag in `products/detail.html`:

```
<form action="{% url question product.pk %}" method="post">
 .... 
</form>
```

---

Or use `reverse` in `detail` view:

```
def detail(request, product_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    f = QuestionForm()
    return render_to_response('products/detail.html', {
        'title' : p.title, 
        'product': p, 
        'action': reverse("question", args=[p.pk,]),
        'form' : f},
    context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

your template:

```
<form action="{{ action }}" method="post">
 .... 
</form>
```

Either way your `question` view would need a line added which actually sets product instance to `Question` attribute:

```
def question(request, product_id):
    ...
    new_question.product = p
```

---

Comment: I had the product_id already in the url, so now i just put it like this: `new_question = f.save(commit=False)` and then this line `new_question.post = p` and then `new_question.save()` and it worked like a charm! Thank you.