# Django formset hidden foreign key

Tags: django, formsets

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621212/another-django-forms-foreign-key-in-hidden-field) question and answer got me 90% of the way there. So thank you community.

I have a modelformset, which validates and goes into the 'if valid' loop

models.py

```
class session_log(models.Model):
    anaesthetist_id = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    session_start_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
    session_end_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
    session_type= models.ForeignKey(session_types, null=True, blank=True)
    session_comments=models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.anaesthetist_id)+" "+str(self.session_start_datetime.date())+" "+str(self.session_type)
```

forms.py

```
class SessionList(forms.ModelForm):

    session_comments = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':1}))
    session_start_datetime = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%y %H:%M',], widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format="%d/%m/%y %H:%M"))    
    session_end_datetime = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%y %H:%M',], widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format="%d/%m/%y %H:%M"))    

    class Meta:
        model = session_log
        exclude = ('anaesthetist_id',)
        fields = ['session_start_datetime', 'session_end_datetime', 'session_comments','session_type']
```

views.py

```
def session_overview(request):


    SessionListFormSet = modelformset_factory(session_log, form=SessionList, extra = 10, exclude =('anaesthetist_id',), can_delete=True)
    x = session_log.objects.filter(anaesthetist_id=request.user.id).count()
    y = x-10
    initialformset = SessionListFormSet(queryset=session_log.objects.filter(anaesthetist_id=request.user.id).order_by("session_start_datetime")[y:])
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        submitted_data = SessionListFormSet(data=request.POST)
        if submitted_data.is_valid():
            for session in submitted_data:
              new_session = session.save(commit=False)
              new_session.anaesthetist_id = request.user
              new_session.save()
```

The x and y are in there to reverse the queryset and give me the last 10 results in descending order, so that you add a new session, usually a later one, to the bottom of the formset. It's a stylistic bodge

The problem is that when I try and save or edit a form I get:

```
IntegrityError at /trainee/dataentry/
NOT NULL constraint failed: trainee_session_log.session_end_datetime
```

But I can bodge it by adding an 'if is not none' in the save loop:

bodged views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':    
    submitted_data = SessionListFormSet(data=request.POST)
    if submitted_data.is_valid():
        for session in submitted_data:
                new_session = session.save(commit=False)
                new_session.anaesthetist_id = request.user
                if new_session.session_end_datetime is not None:
                    new_session.save()
```

I am genuinely at a loss as to why it is that field only that is causing the issue. Clearly that is a total bodge

Am I being really silly?

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined `null=True` for the respective fields. If you want Django to save null values in database, then you may change the lines,

```
session_start_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
session_end_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don;t want it to save null values. These values are required. Every 'session' record needs to have a start_date/time and end_date/time as that is the basis for all the subsequent calculations.

Comment: Your code seems fine. Does the error still persist??

Comment: Yes, If I debug it and loop through each of the 'sessions' in the view I can see that what is happening is that every form from the formset is being passed to the save function, including empty ones. I assume the reason that those fields are causing the issues is that they are the first that are attempted to be saved. I would like error messages to be displayed for non-valid forms within the formset (rules yet to be written) but I do not want error messages for empty forms. I can write that in manually but it seems rather inelegant.